# GoogleScraper on Windows - Error setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have a problem for install GoogleScraper with python. I am lost.
Look my problem :
[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7JkT.jpg)

```sh
 File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_py.py", line 55, in finalize_options

    self.package_dir[name] = convert_path(path)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\util.py", line 127, in convert_path

    raise ValueError("path '%s' cannot end with '/'" % pathname)

ValueError: path 'examples/' cannot end with '/'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir C:\Users\Billy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Billy...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Billy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Billy\GoogleScraper
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Billy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Billy\GoogleScraper
```

I already tried many methods for resolve this problem such as said on the documentation of GoogleScraper https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper#on-windows

I also tried run the command

> python ez_setup.py

But it don't working for me.

Please, help me.

Comment: You are using Python 3.4 maybe a mismatch with versions in pip, distutils ar a specific other package. The value error simply states that a path text variable should not end with a forward slash but what it expects instead I do not know. Is there no documentation on which versions and how to install that module on the wide, wide web?

Comment: You need to provide the log output as **text**. Text searches cannot cope with screenshots, making this question less discoverable.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I had used the documentation of GoogleScraper. PS: I modified my post, I hope that it's good now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem with this solution --> [Github](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper/pull/150/commits/1158b5fe2b9af30e312773cc8d71060c6a134d46)

I had removed a slash in the file "setup.py" for correctly install GoogleScraper.

Go at line 24 for the changing.

```py
        packages=['GoogleScraper'],
        entry_points={'console_scripts': ['GoogleScraper = GoogleScraper.core:main']},
 -      package_dir={'examples': 'examples/'},
 +      package_dir={'examples': 'examples'},
        install_requires=requirements
  )
```

Comment: You can also clone the actual version of the GoogleScraper repo from GitHub, edit the setup.py according Billy's answer. Than you should go to the GoogleScraper root directory and install it with the command: ''pip install -e .''

Comment: @mrbo That's exactly what I had to do, download zip from GitHub, change setup.py, then install with "pip install -e path/to/scraper/dir"